# OnKeyPress event is't fired when Form has a parent

Tags: delphi, parent, keypress, tabbed

I'm trying to implement a TDI interface in my project. It's working fine so far (the forms are created inside tabs on my PageControl - as expected). However, I'm facing an annoying issue: the OnKeyPress event isn't fired on my child forms just because they are "parented". I've tried both ways below, but with no success:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  f: TForm2;
begin
  f := TForm2.Create(self);
  f.ManualDock(PageControl1);
  f.Show;
end;
```

-OR-

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  f: TForm2;
  tab: TTabSheet;
begin
  tab := TTabSheet.Create(PageControl1);
  tab.PageControl := PageControl1;
  tab.Parent := PageControl1;

  f := TForm2.Create(tab);
  f.BorderStyle := bsNone;
  f.Align := alClient;
  f.Parent := tab;
  tab.Caption := f.Caption;

  f.Show;
end;
```

¹ needless to say that the KeyPreview property is set as True.

² if I just comment the following line, the event works fine (but the form is not created inside a TabSheet):

```
//f.Parent := tab;
```

Has anyone faced this issue before? Any help?
Thanks!

Comment: KeyPreview being True explains it. The event goes to the top level form, as designed.

Comment: Normally KeyPreview only makes the form receive the events *in* *addition* to the control, so it should still work.

Comment: It should work, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

I had a look at the sources, it turns out that the control receiving the `KeyPress` searches for its parent form, and if the form has `KeyPreview` set, relays the event to that form:

```
function TWinControl.DoKeyPress(var Message: TWMKey): Boolean;
var
  Form: TCustomForm;
  Ch: Char;
begin
  Result := True;
  Form := GetParentForm(Self);
  if (Form <> nil) and (Form <> Self) and Form.KeyPreview and
    TWinControl(Form).DoKeyPress(Message) then Exit;
  // [...]
  Result := False;
end;
```

The parent form is the top level form in the chain. This means that your `Form1` receives the event (if it has `KeyPreview` set) in addition to the original control:

```
function GetRealParentForm(Control: TControl; TopForm: Boolean = True): TCustomForm;
begin
  while (TopForm or not (Control is TCustomForm)) and (Control.Parent <> nil) do
    Control := Control.Parent;
  if Control is TCustomForm then
    Result := TCustomForm(Control) else
    Result := nil;
end;
```

This leaves you with a couple of options:

- Handle the `KeyPress` in `Form1` instead, though you then probably have to find out which child form it came from originally.
- Set the form's `KeyPreview` to false, and instead add the handler to
  the controls on `Form2` directly.
- Modify the VCL
  source to not relay they `KeyPress` to the top level form, but
  instead to the next form in the chain, I think that's what I would
  do.
- Of course there might be other options I'm not thinking of right now.

Comment: You are right. I'm trying to override this method, but I'm not sure if it'll work as desired.